# Using Pointers safely in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, oop, memory, pointers

Lets say I have an object with an integer instance variables and 1 member function. The function runs on a separate thread, and consistently updates the value of the instance variable. I have a second function (part of a different class) that also runs on a separate thread, and needs real time access to the integer instance variable in the first object. Therefore, I pass in a pointer to the instance variable to the second function and the second function just dereferences the pointer. This way the second function always has access to the updated value of the instance variable.

However, I do not want the second function to be able to change the value of the instance variable. I want it to have read-only access, but since I am passing in a pointer to the instance variable, will it be able to change the value of the instance variable? If so, how do I restrict pointer dereferencing to read only? If this isn't possible, what would be the safest solution to this problem?

Mac OS X Snowleopard, Xcode 3.2.6. Objective-C with Cocoa.

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to mention that I can't make the instance variable constant, because I need the class it belongs to to be able to modify it. If I make it constant, it would completely restricting writing to the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the type system here. Instead of having something like `int*` you can have `const int *`, which means it's a pointer to a constant int. It's possible to get around this by casting back to `(int *)` inside the function, but this is a violation of the type system (hence the explicit cast) and well-behaved functions won't do that.

Note, you may also need to throw in `volatile` if your function needs to make sure it has the up-to-date value. Otherwise the compiler may decide it's ok to cache the results of the dereference somewhere.

Comment: So I need to adjust the arguments to the function not the variable itself right?

Comment: @Farhad: Yes. The function can be declared like `void myfunc(const int *ptr)`, which means it's declaring that it will not ever assign to the dereferenced pointer.

Comment: @Farhad: See `man strcmp` for a good example of this. `strcmp()` declares its arguments as `const char *`, because it will not modify them.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this is make the instance variable a property, and to give the second function a pointer to the object instead of a pointer to the instance variable. The code can then call the object's accessor for the property. It's not clear how your code is structured, but it's also possible to make the property read-only for method outside the class definition, and read-write for methods that are part of the class.

Finally, since you're accessing the property from more than one thread, you'll need to provide some sort of synchronization to avoid having both threads try to access the property at the same time. The simplest way to do that is to omit 'nonatomic' (which is how most people reflexively declare their properties) from the property declaration, which will cause the property accessors to be atomic. The second simplest way is to use the @synchronized directive.

Comment: You actually cannot specify something as `atomic`, you can just omit `nonatomic`. Also, I don't know what the OP's use case is, but using `@synchronized` may very well be far too expensive.

Comment: @KevinBallard What was I thinking?! ;-) Thanks. As far as `@synchronized`, I don't disagree, but I figured that simple and working slowly is better than complicated and not working or random bad data.